# Laptop Keyboard when plugging in usb

Tags: keyboard, laptop

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a MSI laptop for school, It has two USB C ports and one USB A port. Whenever I plug in anything to any of those ports, my keyboard stops working, however the laptop's mousepad still works.